# How to log and record the temperature sensor data from android smartphone?

Tags: android, database, logging, android-sensors

I want to develop an application which records the temperature from the onboard temperature sensor of the smartphone after hourly intervals and saves them in the form of a database to present it later to the user. This has to be done in background. What is the most simple and efficient method of doing both of these operations?

1- Logging Temperature sensor data in background.

2- Saving that data into a database for the user to see later.